# How can I select certain columns in a dataframe based on their number of valid values (except NA) in R?

Tags: r, validation, dataframe

I'm using R, and I have a dataframe with multiple columns. I want to run a code and automatically check the number of values (valid values, not NA) in each column. Then, it should select the columns that 50% of its rows are filled by valid values, and save them in a new dataframe.

Can anybody help me doing this? Thank you very much.

Is there any way that the codes can be applied for an uncertain number of columns?

Comment: `new_data = df[colMeans(is.na(df))<0.5]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr` package, you can write function below to check for the percentage of missing values:

```
pct_missing <- purrr::map_dbl(df,~mean(is.na(.x)))
```

After that, you can select those columns that have less than 50% missing values by their names.

```
selected_column <- colnames(df)[pct_missing < 0.5]
```

To create a new dataset, you may use:

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% select(one_of(selected_column))
```

Comment: Thank you, That was so helpful. 
How can I select those valid columns and create a new dataset automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function within R base also to automatically retrieve the colums matching the critria:

Function:

```
ColSel <- function(df){
vals <- apply(df,2, function(fo) mean(is.na(fo))) < .5
return(df[,vals])
}
```

Some toy data

```
## example
df1 <- data.frame(
    a = c(runif(19),NA),
    b = c(rep(NA,11),runif(9)),
    d = rep(NA,20),
    e = runif(20)
    )
```

Test

```
df2 <- ColSel(df1)
```